# How to fix compilepkg: missing strict dependency on golang.org/x/sys/unix when building Bazel project?

Tags: go, build, bazel

I am trying to get a local version of [this repository](https://github.com/google/simhospital/tree/master) running on my PC. I am on Debian 12 and have installed Bazel v6.4.0 and Go v1.21.5. I am not that familiar with Go and much less so with Bazel.

When I run the [command suggested in the setup instructions to build the project](https://github.com/google/simhospital/blob/master/docs/get-started.md), namely `bazel //...`, I get the following error:

```
DEBUG: /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle/internal/go_repository.bzl:184:18: org_golang_google_grpc: gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
gazelle: finding module path for import golang.org/x/sys/unix: exit status 1: go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys/unix
go: found golang.org/x/sys/unix in golang.org/x/sys v0.15.0
found packages unix (affinity_linux.go) and main (mkasm.go) in /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/bazel_gazelle_go_repository_cache/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.15.0/unix
INFO: Analyzed 131 targets (171 packages loaded, 1946 targets configured).
INFO: Found 131 targets...
ERROR: /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/external/com_github_sirupsen_logrus/BUILD.bazel:3:11: GoCompilePkg external/com_github_sirupsen_logrus/go_default_library.a failed: (Exit 1): builder failed: error executing command (from target @com_github_sirupsen_logrus//:go_default_library) bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6-ST-625e526ca8a8/bin/external/go_sdk/builder compilepkg -sdk external/go_sdk -installsuffix linux_amd64 -src external/com_github_sirupsen_logrus/alt_exit.go -src ... (remaining 45 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
compilepkg: missing strict dependencies:
        /home/henry/.cache/bazel/_bazel_henry/cefbbfcdd1c1bdf63e873be5150774b3/sandbox/linux-sandbox/183/execroot/__main__/external/com_github_sirupsen_logrus/terminal_check_unix.go: import of "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
No dependencies were provided.
Check that imports in Go sources match importpath attributes in deps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 12.435s, Critical Path: 0.96s
INFO: 31 processes: 12 internal, 19 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I have tried adding the following to the WORKSPACE file but it results in the same error

```
go_repository(
    name = "org_golang_x_sys",
    importpath = "github.com/golang/sys",
    commit = "13b15b780d9013988b1fb0e79e30b2528a877638",
)
```

Importing `golang.org/x/sys/unix` works fine elsewhere on my system using the usual Go import process, so I reckon it's something to do with the Bazel configuration. **Can any Bazel expert help me fix this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was on the right lines, but hadn't added the repository to the `WORKSPACE` file correctly.

Running `bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos golang.org/x/sys@v0.13.0` added the following lines to my `WORKSPACE` file and the build succeeded.

```
go_repository(
    name = "org_golang_x_sys",
    importpath = "golang.org/x/sys",
    sum = "h1:Af8nKPmuFypiUBjVoU9V20FiaFXOcuZI21p0ycVYYGE=",
    version = "v0.13.0",
)
```